# Не переведено сообщение о дополнении вопроса модератором

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, инструменты-модератора

В [ревизии вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3753/revisions) присутствует текст:

> appended answer 3755 as supplemental

[image: appended]

Допускаю, что текст мог быть указан явно @NickVolynkin :) но не думаю, что стоило тут писать по английски. В transifex упомянутой фразы не нашёл.

Comment: А фикса всё нет... Свежий пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/950761/revisions

Comment: Вероятно, фикс уже есть?

Comment: @andreymal можно флагать модератора с просьбой пометить красным "статус-завершено"

Comment: @andreymal [фикс](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300580/339911)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема исправлена.

Некоторые подробности на MSE:

[Localization issue when mod converts answer to the part of question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300580/339911)